# Unable to deploy to Heroku, no changes were made

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

I'm running into a deployment issue with Heroku. Yesterday, I was able to deploy without issues -- this morning, I built a new cluster on MongoDB and pushed a change to git with the new connection string. No other changes were made.

After pushing to git, I ran `git push heroku master`, and was faced with the below error:

```
. . .
remote:        added 1812 packages from 857 contributors and audited 932744 packages in 66.192s
remote:        
remote:        65 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_3fd8925946ec2800b115594ca20fb426/client
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        ./node_modules/simple-react-lightbox/dist/index.es.js
remote:        Cannot find module: 'fast-deep-equal/react'. Make sure this package is installed.
remote:        
remote:        You can install this package by running: yarn add fast-deep-equal/react.
. . .
```

Naturally, the first thing I did was try to run `yarn add fast-deep-equal/react` as advised, which threw the next error,

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/fast-deep-equal/react.git
Directory: /Users/me/my-app
Output:
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've been debugging for several hours now, and I can't seem to figure out a solution.

What could be going on here?

Comment: Not answer to the OP but you should set your connection string in an environment variable

Answer (score 1):

Try running `yarn add epoberezkin/fast-deep-equal`

Yarn appears to be trying to install the library from the wrong github repository. This is likely the fault of Heroku's error message not telling you the correct module name.

Comment: This resolved this error message, however it threw another one, `could not locate module ./temp/..../index.js`. I ended up getting rid of simple-react-lightbox for now.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case when I tried to deploy to Heroku I got identical messages. After trying some things (at random) I found the problem is the **devDependencies**. You would rather transfer all of them to normal dependencies:

```
npm install <module_name> --save-prod
```

That solved my error, good luck!